# Where do the Hyperspace Routes in Star Wars Come From

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, hyperspace

Where did the Hyperspace Routes in the Star Wars universe originate from in the first place, Also is there only one route on and off a planet? Or can a world have multiple Hyperspace routes?

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hyperspace_route

Comment: I think you have a misapprehension about what "hyperspace route" means.  It's not like there's a single road you must use, it's more like there certain regions of space that are surveyed and known to be safe for travel.  Kind of like a shipping channel marked by bouys for safer navigation.

Comment: That makes sense as starships are depicted in a similar fashion as our earthbound seafaring ships the Imperial fleet is sometimes referred to as the “Imperial Navy” So yes I can see the similarities..

Answer (score 2):

In Legends canon, hyperspace routes were discovered by the Hyperspace Navigator's Guild:

> **Hyperspace Navigator's Guild** This ancient guild was responsible for the discovery, cataloging, and availability of hyperspace routes. Founded originally on the planet Empress Teta, the guild was made up of daring explorers who braved the unknowns of deep space to find quicker ways to get from one major trade center to another. Once a new route was discovered, the right to use the route was sold by the guild, with a percentage of the royalties going to pay the explorers who found it. The guild existed without major change for many millennia until New Order (sic), when the Empire raided the guild's computers and made off with whatever information it wanted.
>
> <sub>(Source: *The Complete Star Wars Encyclopedia* (2008), Vol II (H-O), page 71, entry "Hyperspace Navigator's Guild")</sub>

*The Essential Atlas* shows some planets located along a single trade route, while others are located at the nexus of several, such as Coruscant Corellia, and Brentaal. It also elaborates on how known routes are maintained:

> Updating and recalculating well-known routes is the duty of the Space Ministry. Updates are available for a nominal fee from ministry offices or downloaded as a standard part of docking procedures at many spaceports. As part of the same process, route and sensor data from starships' navicomputers is routinely uploaded and collected for analysis by the ministry's astrogation bureau, after which it becomes part of new updates. Refusal to share navicomputer about established routes is illegal, and almost universally condemned by spacers as selfish and dangerous. That doesn't apply to data about new routes, however: Scouts, smuglers, and legitimate captains all guard such knowledge jealously. Put any group of spacers in a cantina and within a couple of rounds they'll be telling fanciful tales of spacer guilds, shipping companies, and entire species that supposedly make their living from secret trade routes.
>
> <sub>(Source: *The Essential Atlas* (2009), page 14)</sub>

Comment: Does the encyclopedia explain how the guild enforced their fees? Was all ship navigation done by guild members? Otherwise, I don't understand how they could keep the routes secret.

Comment: @PM2Ring "The right to use the route" and the term "royalties" suggest that the routes aren't secret, but traders need a license to use them legally. If they don't, presumably the guild takes them to court to collect.

Comment: @PM2Ring _The Essential Atlas_ has some details on this, answer updated. The guild isn't mentioned by name, but could take a cut of the Ministry's fees, or maybe it's kept afloat by the same sorts of people who pay for WinRAR.